# Использовать данные из config файла в своем приложении

Tags: php

Есть конфиг файл со след. содержанием. Подскажите, пожвлуйста, как потом можно использовать эти данные в своем прилржении?

```
<?php
return array(
    //  MySQL database details
    'database' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'collation' => 'utf8_bin'
    ),

    // Application settings
    'application' => array(
        // url paths
        'default_controller' => 'index',
        'default_action' => 'index',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
    ),

    // Session details
    'session' => array(
        'name' => '',
        'expire' => 3600,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => ''
    ),

    // Error handling
    'error' => array(
        'ignore' => array(E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED),
        'detail' => false,
        'log' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: .

    $config = include 'file.php';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну если вы инклудите этот конфиг через

```
$config = include 'file.php';
```

То потом, например к хосту можете обратиться  `$config['database']['host']`. Ну и аналогично к другим полям.